# ループ処理を指定回数ループさせる

Tags: ruby

１から５の数字を表示する処理を３回繰り返そうとして

```
#! ruby -Ks
#! ruby -Ks
# coding: windows-31j
# helloruby G05.rb
STDOUT.sync = true 

a=1
b=0
loop do
print a,"\n"
a=a+1
if a == 5
b=b+1
redo
end
if b == 3
break
end
```

としようとすると例によって
ggruby.rb:19:syntax error,unexpected end-of-input,expecting keyword_end
と言われます
どこにendが足りないのか探しても分かりません
どなたか分かる方教えて下さい。

Comment: エラーメッセージ(`ggruby.rb:19:...`)の `19` は行番号になります。つまり、`ggruby.rb` ファイルの 19 行目に `end` を置く必要があります。ところで、19行目に `end` を入れて実行すると無限ループになりますのでご注意下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loop do`に対する`end`が足りません。
インデントを付けると分かりやすいです。

```
loop do
    print a,"\n"
    a=a+1
    if a == 5
        b=b+1
        redo
    end
    if b == 3
        break
    end
end
```

---

ちなみに
`redo`は必要無い(`if b == 3` が実行されない。)です。

```
a=a+1
if a == 5
```

（加算した後に１つのループの終わりのチェックとする）だと`5`が表示されないです。
それで`a=a+1`の位置を変える必要があります。（またはチェックを`a > 5` に変更する、など）
また、１セットの表示終わりに`a`をリセットする必要があります。
なので
アプローチをなるべく変えないで期待する動作のためにはループ部分を以下のようにします。
一例：

```
loop do
    print a,"\n"
    if a == 5
        b=b+1
        a = 0
    end
    a=a+1
    if b == 3
        break
    end
end
```

---

単純にｎ回繰り返すという場合には`times`を使った方が分かりやすいと思います。
１～５というような繰り返しも`Range`を使った方が分かりやすいです。
例：

```
3.times do
    for v in 1..5
        print v, "\n";
    end
end
```